# Is there a font or (better!) set of unicode characters representing the numbers 0-255 for displaying ASCII character codes (or other uses)?

Tags: windows, unicode, console, non-printing-characters

I have strings that are mostly standard alpha-numeric and other printable ASCII characters, and would like to display these in a console window on Windows. What I'm looking for is either a console font or a unicode set of characters that represent the numbers 0-255 (0-FF) using a single glyph for each. The thing that comes closest that I am aware of is that unicode has a small set of circled numbers, 1-20, and elsewhere numbers 21-50. Something along those lines, but for 0-255 (or 0-FF) is what I'm trying to find.

It seems to me that this would be a relatively common need/desire, but I've been unable to track down a solution. Any help appreciated!

Comment: What if the answer to this question will be a "NO", in spite of the "relatively common need/desire"?

Comment: I made a font like that once, with glyphs looking like `00`, `01` etc through `FF`. Is that what you need? I'm not at all sure I can find it again though, that was 20 years ago.

Comment: @Claudio- then I will be disappointed?

Comment: @MrLister yes, this is what I am thinking of. Had done the same thing for a dumb terminal that supported software defined glyphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C0 and C1 controls can be represented by [control pictures](https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/c_2400.html). The rest of the C0 Controls and Basic Latin, and C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement [blocks](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) can be represented by themselves. You may have to test a few fonts to find one that supports all these characters.

However, you said "ASCII" and "0-255". But, ASCII has only 128 codepoints. Your codepoints 128-255 must be from an unnamed character set. Although you probably mean one of the well-known ones, they are so numerous that a detailed answer isn't practical.

There is also the [Unicode BMP Fallback SIL font](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=unicodebmpfallbackfont#7cd8fb6e) that covers U+0000 to U+FFFF (but not U+10000 to U+10FFFF).

Comment: The downloadable font you linked to is definitely the right idea, if overkill. Sorry for my incorrect usage of ASCII -- I should have said any 8-bit unsigned character. Looking for something that simply displays the numeric value; not any conventional names associated with those values.

Comment: So if you want to display binary data as character, such as by using that font, you would decode the bytes as ISO 8858-1 to maintain the numerical value (0xC0 becomes U+00C0 and is shown as the character that looks like 00 C0).